# CalendarView создание собственного календаря с событиями

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, хочу написать свой календарть, с добавлением/редактированием событий. И тд, по сути полноценный ежедневник, с напоминаниями и тд.
Нашел в интернете пример, в основе лежит CalendarView.  Но никаких методов, кроме onDateSetChange не нашел. 
Хочется по нажатию на дату, переходить в детали.
Скролить спокойно.
И тд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть отличный виджет от небезызвестной Square — [тык](https://github.com/square/android-times-square). На случай, если вам вдруг не захочется изобретать свой велосипед. Хотя, по большому счёту, там и с нуля не слишком-то долго его делать.

---

А касательно "хочется по нажатию на дату переходить в детали" — `CalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener()` вам поможет.

Comment: @falstaf когда в этот метод вставляю переход в другой фрагмент, у меня при скролинге он срабатывает